# How can i set up an open ported vpn to bypass closed ports

Tags: port, vpn, 3g, rdp

I have **3g** **modem** **connection**, so i can't open ports, i have to RDP windows 2008 and centOS.

I have used some free vpn that successefuly opened my ports, but as you know these free vpn are extermely slow.
I was wondering how can i create an open ported vpn, so i can open ports in it
thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

If you only need a couple of ports, SSH might be an easier to set up alternative, as it can do port forwarding (traffic is routed through the ssh connection). Just run the ssh daemon on the machine, where ports are accessible from the outside, connect to it from the one on 3G and forward all ports you need (you can choose the direction of the forward, so it can work both ways).

Comment: thank you for the answer, but how can i connect to the server with my 3g ? i'm on windows 7 64bit